# AUC ROC and Recall always gives the same value?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am doing a binary classification task and I am calculating the `AUC ROC` and the `Recall` as follows :

```
  recall= metrics.recall_score(y_test,y_pred,pos_label=None,average='macro')
  auc=roc_auc_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

and I always end up wit the exact same value for both ( `recall = auc` )! I have no idea why this is happening .. any help ?!

Comment: They are not the same thing. Please give data set for us to debug.

Comment: I have changed the recall calculation to the following and now it gives me different score .. does this make sense ?.... `recall= metrics.recall_score(y_test,y_pred)` .. it seems that when I calculate for each class ( the macro ) it gives the same as the AUC ! I have also calculate the AUC using the function `auc` to make sure of the result and it gave me the same as `roc_auc_score`

Comment: Please give out dataset so we can check.